# Select specific text in specific column of CSV with variable text length

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm working on a CSV file in Notepad++, and I need to match a specific occurance of a set number of characters in the text. Example data:

```
19256506_1.MSG,19256506,1.MSG,RE: New Consent Language,
19256505_1.MSG,19256505,1.DOCX,RE: New Consent Language,
19256433_1.MSG,19256433,1.MSG,RE: New Consent Language,
```

What I need to select is the file extensions in the 3rd row, leaving only the number. The problem is, it could either be `.MSG`, `.DOCX`, `.PDF`, etc. Basically, I need to select anything in the 3rd column after and including the `.`, but up to and excluding the next `,`.

How can I match this using regex?

Comment: How about something like [`^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^.,]*\K\.\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/7YtOZr/1)

Comment: @bobblebubble That works in the demo you linked, but Notepad++ won't recognize it

Comment: @WR7500 Are you working in Linux? I remember the flavors differ a bit between Windows and Linux NPP versions. `\K` works flawlessly, `^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^.,]*\.\K\w+` matches `MSG`, `DOCX` and `MSG` before `,RE` in all three lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^.,]*(\.[^,]+)
```

Use the first group, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/NfCVg6/2/).

Comment: Thank you. While this does select the correct data in the first group, how can I tell Notepad++ to select the 1st group in this selection?

Comment: That selects the first line only. When I plug the original regex into NP++, it will select the entire line up to and including the file extension. I only need what is selected in the 1st group though.

Answer (score -1):

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> (or Search > Replace)  and try replacing:

```
(?s)^(?:[^,]*,){2}[^,]*(\.[^,]+).*?$
```

With

```
\1
```

Make sure Search Mode is set to Regular Expression

Hit <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LcUhLO/1%22Demo%22)